# Cannot disable SSLv3 on Amazon Linux Instance

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I am using SSL Certificate issued by Go Daddy. 
On my Linux Instance following are the software details :-

- Apache Version  - Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon)
- Openssl Version - OpenSSL 1.0.2c 12 Jun 2015
- mod_ssl version - mod_ssl-2.4.2

**Note :- I install Apache from RPM Package and later I install mod_ssl and openssl from source code.**

1) The problem is when I disable SSLv3 and test SSL Server from  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ it gives me warning that **"this server does not support TLSv1.2 which is current best"** and when I enable TLSv1.2 protocol the same test warns me about **"This server supports SSLv3 protocol and vulnerable to Poodle attack"** 
How to disable SSLv3 and enable TLSv1.2 at same time on server?
Current configuration of my Vhost file about SSL is:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
```

2) I cannot create a Strong Diffie-Hellman Group. Current is 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman group and want to create 2048-bit group for the site. 
I issue this command to generate 2048-bit key:-

```
openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048
```

and my configuration in VHost is:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters /etc/httpd/dhparams.pem
```

when I restart server error message pop up:

```
Invalid command 'SSLOpenSSLConfCmd', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For apache http server, try:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
```

Comment: When I do this it warn me about "this server does not support TLSv1.2 which is current best".

Comment: Should I make changes in SSLCipherSuite also

Answer (score 1):

Since you are deploying your instance in Amazon, I guess you were following this tutorial as I was doing: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

In that tutorial, you are kind of encouraged to use Letsencrypt to obtain a free CA, which I also did. After a lot of research trying to alter the ssl.conf file without any success, I found out that Letsencrypt has its own configuration file that overrides whatever you type in the ssl.conf file. Just navigate to

`./etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf`

and type in your changes there as you were instructed to do in the ssl.conf file. After that, just restart apache and your alterations should now take effect.